# Spring Security Authentication issue: HTTP 401

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've encountered a bizarre situation using spring security. Having used:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

With following simple security configuration:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        UserDetails user = User.builder().username("1").password("1").roles("USER").build();
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(user).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/inquiry").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll().and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

I constantly get the `401` Http Status code. But I dig deeper into the code and I've realized that in the spring security core there is a minor issue.
The class `DaoAuthenticationProvider` tries to check if the provided password matches the actual credential with password encoder(in my case `BCrypt`) in hand. So

```
if (!passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword()))
```

But in the encoder, the method signature of `matches` is:

```
public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword)
```

So the authentication fails.

Comment: I followed [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-password-hashing-example/) and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use in-memory authentication with BCrypt in your security configuration, you need to encrypt the password string first.

So you can try

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    // First encrypt the password string
    String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder().encode("1");

    // Set the password
    UserDetails user = User.builder()
                           .username("1")
                           .password(encodedPassword)
                           .roles("USER")
                           .build();

    // Use in-memory authentication with BCryptEncoder
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser(user)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: Nice one! You can drop explicit setup at `passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())` because you are already providing `@Bean PasswordEncoder` and Spring will take care of injecting it as default one. BTW, it is not a good idea to encode passwords from plaintext at runtime. Provide only encoded passwords in source code!

Comment: Nice suggestion @TheStrikeBone. The in-memory authentication is not appropriate for production env. So I provided the solution according to the question. As you mentioned encoding password at runtime is a bad practice.